# How can I resolve this JVM error in SAS EG

Tags: java, plot, sas, jvm, enterprise-guide

I am trying to run the following code in my SAS EG:

```
Data sashelp.air;

proc sgplot data=sashelp.air;
    histogram AIR /;
    yaxis grid;
    run;
```

The following error is coming up:

```
ERROR: Unable to load the Java Virtual Machine. 
Please see the installation instructions or system administrator.
```

For any type of plotting, the same error is coming up.
Please suggest solutions and what the reasons for the issue could be.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing graph format in EG settings.

Tools > Options > Results > Graph

There are 2 dropdown menus, try PNG in both.